# Azure AKS - give entire cluster access to Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to find a way to give an entire AKS cluster to Azure Key vault. I have temporarily got this working by following the below process:

- Go to the VMSS of the cluster -> Identity -> Set System Assigned Status to 'On'
- Add this Managed identity as an access policy to Key Vault.

This works, however whenever I stop and start the cluster, I have to re-create this managed identity and re-add it to Key Vault. I have tried using the User Assigned Identities for the vmss as well but that does not seem to work.

I also cannot use the azure pod identities/CSI features for other reasons so I'm just looking for a simple way to give my cluster permanent access to key Vault.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stopping cluster will lose all the pods under VMSS. So, there will be no pod under VMSS until you restart. In case you will restart your cluster, the new pod will create with different name. MIC (Managed Identity Cluster) removes the identity from the underlying VMSS when no pods are configured to use that identity. So, you have to recreate the Managed Identity for VMSS. You can refer the [blog](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/issues/898).

Answer (score 0):

- Pod is smallest unit in Kubernetes. Pod is a group of one or more containers that are deployed together on the **same hos**t (node).
- Pod runs a node which is controlled by master.
- Pod uses **OS level virtualization** which can consume resources of VMSS when it runs and based on requirement.

***Stopping and restarting cluster/nodes pod will lose all the resources that leads to loss of pods***. So, there will be no pod under VMSS until you restart. ***In case you restart your cluster/node, the new pod will be created with different name and with another IP address.***

From this [github](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/issues/898) discussion, I found that ***MIC** (Managed Identity Cluster) removes the identity from the underlying VMSS when no pods are configured to use that identity.* So, you have to recreate the Managed Identity for VMSS.

You can **refer** this [link](https://csa-ocp-ger.github.io/unicorn/challenges.aadpodidentity.html) for better understanding how to access keyvault from Azure AKS.

Comment: Hey @adan11! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?